# Can I delete my way to an Unsung Hero badge?

Tags: support, zero-score-badges

Bad practices aside, if I delete a bunch of my answers that didn't get accepted, will that count toward the badge?

**UPDATE**

Wow, that's some very negative feedback for a legitimate question.  Did it occur to you that I wasn't asking for badge whoring purposes, but rather satisfy my curiousity about a possible loophole in the system?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, because unaccepted answers are irrelevant to the badge.

The badge requires:

```
Zero score accepted answers: more than 10 and 25% of total
```

To get the badge you need 11 or more accepted answers that have a score of zero, and these zero-scoring accepted answers must form more than 25% of all your accepted answers.

Answers younger than 10 days old, Community Wiki answers, deleted answers, and self-accepted answers are not considered for this calculation.

You might also want to check out [List of all badges with full descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions).

Comment: Thank you for a straight answer.  That's what I wanted to know.

Answer (score 6):

Why do you want the badge that bad? I haven't scored any more women since i got it, it didn't make me a better athlete or a smarter person.

Personally i would rather leave my answers intact and hope they pick up more votes (you realise you can only delete answers that have votes to achieve this, right? Non-voted answers are still candidates to get you there).

Comment: you haven't scored because women prefer sung heroes :)

Comment: @NickDandoulakis oh ho ho ho, that's very clever. +1 Internet to you Sir

Comment: Alas, the conversation devolves into bawdy humor...